# Remove or hide the submit button on search block in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, search, theming

I need to do some custom theming on the search block in Drupal 7.

Specifically, **I need to add a class to the submit button that makes it invisible and removes it from the content flow.**  So:

```
<div class="form-actions form-wrapper" id="edit-actions">
  <input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Search" class="form-submit">
</div>
```

Becomes...

```
<div class="form-actions form-wrapper element-invisible" id="edit-actions">
  <input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Search" class="form-submit">
</div>
```

I added `element-invisible` to the edit-actions div element.  However, I can't figure out how to do this.  What's the best practice for doing this sort of thing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of the standard ways to do this would be to use [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and add the attributes to the actions element directly:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
    $form['actions']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'element-invisible';
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah if I can fully understand the way Drupal loads up it's arrays when dealing with forms I'll have a much happier time with this system.  I love Drupal now, but when I finally figure that aspect of it out, I'll be in theming heaven.

Comment: Yeah it's a tricky one to get your head round at first but it's so powerful it really is worth learning about

Answer (score -1):

You can also hide it using a php condition like this:

```
<?php
function your_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'your_form_id') {
      unset($form['actions']['submit']);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: This can cause form submission not to work properly. FAPI checks for the presence of the triggering element before accepting input.