# How do I disable or completely remove the save configuration button in module's admin page?

Tags: forms

If my question is not broad enough, please tell me and I'll give more detail. I didn't know how to ask the question. Yeah, this is my question...

I am using drupal 7. I have a module and I would like to make a configuration form to my module in admin page. I have given the path and created the forms but there is just one problem. The "Save Configuration" button that comes by default.

What I am trying to do is to add information to the database. I have one submit button for that. I also showed the current rows in my database table with table select in the configuration page. I have another button to delete the selected elements from the database also. So that means I don't need the "Save configuration" button in my case. How can I disable or completely remove the "Save Configuration" button? Thanks.

Comment: Its already answered. Refer http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24144/remove-or-hide-the-submit-button-on-search-block-in-drupal-7.

Comment: That's not really an answer to this question because I believe OP is calling system_settings_form() when it's not needed. A good answer would say why it should not be called in this case.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong Thanks for your opinion. But the code snippet given in the answer solves my problem. I have added this line `$form['actions']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'element-invisible';` into my `hook_form` and my problem was solved.

Comment: Are you calling systems_settings_form(), though? If so, you are also possibly storing the data as config variables as well as generating a button you don't need. If you are calling it, remove it, as it will be useless in this case.